# atof() function doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, c++, c, qt, qt-creator

I have written an App with QT for Android. This is a test App and I found accidentally that when I call the function `atof()` the App crashes at my Samsung s3.

This is the error:

> W/dalvikvm(23038): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417acda0)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(23038): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   E/AndroidRuntime(23038): Process: org.qtproject.example.App_Android, PID: 23038
>   E/AndroidRuntime(23038): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "atof" referenced by "libApp_Android.so"...

and the code is:

```
char str[20]; strcpy(str, "98993489");
val = atof(str);
```

from tutorialpoint.com.

Why do I have this issue? How can I solve it?

Comment: Any reason you can't switch to `std::string` and use [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)?

Comment: If you use Qt then use Qt API: [toDouble](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toDouble) [toFloat](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toFloat).